# Conflicting problems with ASP.NET Core Web API as either x86 or x64

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

My ASP.NET Core Web API project, which targets .NET 6, contains a dependency to a 32-bit COM DLL, and uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to read user data from a SQL Server database for authenticating the supplied basic credentials.

If I set the platform target to x64 and have the Application Pool be set to enable 32-bit applications, when I make the call to my anonymous action, as a test, Postman shows this error:

`HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start`

And in the Application event log I see this error:

`Application '/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\MyAPI\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.`

If I change the Application Pool be disable 32-bit applications, the anonymous method responds correctly with valid JSON, but I see this error recorded by my exception handler in the API:

`Exception: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {31336821-F462-4D84-9673-3F7C7E7CE411} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))`

This will be because the 64-bit process cannot initialise the 32-bit COM DLL, as the 32-bit DLL registration is in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node hive and the 64-bit process is looking in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive. I know about this, and enabling 32-bit applications in the pool is the supposed solution, but that doesn't work for me.

Putting this aside for now, using the 64-bit API with 32-bit applications disabled, if I call one of the API actions that uses Basic Authentication, the DLL is connecting to the database, retrieving the list of users, and authenticating the supplied credentials against that list.

Postman shows 200 OK and the correct JSON for the action.

So to resolve the COM problem, I changed the project to target x86 instead, rebuild and publish to IIS with win-x86 target runtime.

Restarting the website, without altering the pool, and calling my anonymous action, I get back

`HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start`

and

`Application '/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\MyAPI\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.`

Go to the pool advanced settings and Enable 32-bit Application. Now my anonymous method returns the correct JSON, and more importantly, the initialisation of the COM server succeeds as I no longer see the COM class factory error.

Then I call my basic authentication method, which worked before when it was 64-bit, and it returns 401 Unathorized in Postman, with no JSON.

Reviewing the exception handler log, I can see that when initialising the user repository which retrieves the user data from the database, it has recorded:

`Exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.`

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package but that didn't resolve the issue. I saw a stackoverflow post about re-installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI, but that package says it is not meant for direct consumption, and there doesn't appear to be a x86 version.

What this seems to be implying is that Microsoft.Data.SqlClient doesn't exist for 32-bit .NET applications, and there isn't a 32-bit specific version of the NuGet package for this class, but there is a x86 version of System.Data.SqlClient runtime, so do I have to use that class instead?

Comment: I changed a x64 sqlclient project to x86 but works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and replaced it with `System.Data.SqlClient`, and now my x86 DLL doesn't throw a `TdsParser` exception and everything is working.